# Box shadow glow effect for ie

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I've used css3's box-shadow not to create an shadow but to add an glow effect. It works just fine but of course except for IE. Is there some workarround to make it possible in IE?

The css I'm using right now:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; 
box-shadow:0 0 5px #666;
```

I already looked at IE PIE but it doesn't work because I use too much z-index. Also

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

won't work, it does display shadow but I can't seem to make it look like an glow effect.

Does someone know another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

This is a compatibility hack for IE which enables all versions of IE to support several CSS3 features, including `box-shadow`.

You add the Pie.htc `behavior` style to your existing stylesheet, and it will read the standard `box-shadow` styles that you've already written for other browsers.

No more hacking around with the horrible `filter` syntax! It just uses the standard CSS.

In short, you can replace that whole `filter` line with `behavior:url('pie.htc');`

Pie also implements `border-radius` and gradients.

These features could all already be done in IE of course (otherwise how would Pie work), but Pie makes them much easier to implement because it makes IE read the standard styles.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You know he already mentioned that he looked into CSS3Pie, right?